# Standard for creating JWT in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, jwt

I am struggling to figure out a way to standardize JWT creation across a product.
Following are the two implementations that i have come across

1. Uses JwtSecurityToken where audience can be null and in this implementation, we have used a clientspecific GUID as a audienceID

   ```
       string audienceId = data.Properties.Dictionary.ContainsKey(AudiencePropertyKey) ? data.Properties.Dictionary[AudiencePropertyKey] : null;

       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(audienceId)) throw new InvalidOperationException("AuthenticationTicket.Properties does not include audience");

       ClientDataModel audience = ClientStore.FindAudience(audienceId);

       string symmetricKeyAsBase64 = audience.Base64Secret;

       var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);

       var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);

       var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;
       var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

       //Generate Token based on the Passed information as Parameters
       var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);


       var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

       //Write Token in the JWT Format
       var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);

       return jwt;
   ```
2. Using SecurityTokenDescriptor where AppliesToAddress is a must and throws an error in case it is not provided. As per oauth specification, audience is a optional parameter

   ```
       var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
       var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
       string symmetricKeyAsBase64 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AudienceSecret"];

       var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);
       var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);

       // Token Creation
       var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
       {
           Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
           {
                   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, ""),
           }),
           TokenIssuerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Issuer"],
           AppliesToAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppliesToAddress"],
           Lifetime = new Lifetime(now, now.AddMinutes(Int32.Parse((string)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenValidFor"]))),
           SigningCredentials = signingKey
       };

       JwtSecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor) as JwtSecurityToken;
       return token.RawData;
   ```

Can someone suggest which one to use?